# Play migration 2.0.3 to 2.2

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, migration, playframework-2.2

Trying to migrate to play framework 2.2 from 2.0.3. Followed the guide. Everythng seems to be fine except the routes.

```
not enough arguments for method apply: (ref: AnyRef, routerPackage: String, controller: String,    method: String, parameterTypes: Seq[Class[_]], verb: String, comments: String, path: String)play.core.Router.HandlerDef in object HandlerDef.

[error] Unspecified value parameter path.
[error] GET           /                                          controllers.apps.Home.home()
```

Apparantly home() does not require any params either. Iam not sure wat this error is implying. Is there anything Iam missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Removing all the files in the target folder seems to do the trick. Ideally `play clean` should have did it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help to someone. I've changed scalaVersion := "2.10.4" to scalaVersion := "2.11.1" and deleted `playScalaSetting` line from `build.sbt`. This perfect for me! Play2 is currently being ported to Scala 2.10 and its API is very unstable right now. [Original here](https://github.com/sgodbillon/reactivemongo-tailablecursor-demo/issues/2).